# How make "ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#current_page?" works with request method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I have menu with current page highlighting items, implemented via **current_page?** method

```
  def cp(*paths)
    'current' if paths.any? { |path| current_page?(path) }
  end
```

Menu items look like this

```
  <li>
    <%= link_to 'Sign up', signup_path, class: cp(signup_path, new_user_path, {controller: :users, action: :create}) %>
  </li>
```

Users#create method (called on *POST /users*) just renders *:new* when error happens, and menu item not highlights.

I'm using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When fields don't pass validation